# Add dynamic title Tag in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add a Dynamic title in a 'a' tag using Jquery

Now in the HTML I have this:

```
<a href="link" title="Bad title1">Epic Text Link1</a>
<a href="link" title="Bad title2">Epic Text Link2</a>
<a href="link" title="Bad title3">Epic Text Link3</a>
<a href="link" title="Bad title4">Epic Text Link4</a>
```

And I need by Jquery first delete the title and them add a title similar than the text.

Now in Jquery I have this:

```
$("#ClassForThisPart a").removeAttr("title")
```

But this just remove the existing title

Comment: All you need to answer your question is a simple Google [search](https://www.google.gr/search?btnI=1&q=add+attribute+jquery); even if feeling lucky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "add a title SIMILAR than the TEXT."

OP wants the title to be replaced with what is currently the text value.

To add a title based on what the text of your anchor tags are, use a combination of `.attr()` and `.text()`

```
$( "#ClassForThisPart a" ).attr( "title", function() {
   return $(this).text();
 });
```

Comment: Can't use `this` in arrow function

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify @charlietfl's comment, you can use `this` in arrow functions, it just means something different: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/

Answer (score 2):

For changing the inner text of attributes, use `attr()` instead of `removeAttr()`.
`attr()` is used to assign the inner text in attributes where `removeAttr()`is used to remove the particular attribute from the element.
In your case,

```
$("#ClassForThisPart a").attr("title","Whatever the new value is");
```

Comment: Does not answer the OP goal of "add a title SIMILAR than the TEXT." OP wants the title to be replaced with what is currently the text value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove the attribute and then add it again, you can simply use the `attr()` method to assign a new value to the attribute:

```js
$("#ClassForThisPart a").attr("title", "new title");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ClassForThisPart">
  <a href="link" title="Bad title1">Epic Text Link1</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title2">Epic Text Link2</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title3">Epic Text Link3</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title4">Epic Text Link4</a>
</div>
```

If you still prefer to to remove the attribute and then add it again, there is no `addAttr()` method in jQuery, so you'll also use the `attr()` method which seems redundant here:

```js
$("#ClassForThisPart a").removeAttr("title").attr("title", "new title");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ClassForThisPart">
  <a href="link" title="Bad title1">Epic Text Link1</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title2">Epic Text Link2</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title3">Epic Text Link3</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title4">Epic Text Link4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and return the text for each element instance in the callback or whatever modification you want of that text

```js
$("#ClassForThisPart a").attr('title', function(i, oldTitle) {
  return this.textContent;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ClassForThisPart">
  <a href="link" title="Bad title1">Epic Text Link1</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title2">Epic Text Link2</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title3">Epic Text Link3</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title4">Epic Text Link4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My HTML

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="link" title="Bad title1">Epic Text Link1</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title2">Epic Text Link2</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title3">Epic Text Link3</a>
  <a href="link" title="Bad title4">Epic Text Link4</a>
</div>
```

You can loop over the all  elements by using `.each()`

```
$(".links a").each(function(i, elem){
    var title = $(elem).attr('title');
    $(elem).text(title);
 });
```